# My 'subscription' in-app-purchase gets cancelled everytime. How to turn my subscription auto-renewable?

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription, android-inapp-purchase, google-play-billing

I got a situation.
I have implemented for in-app subscription purchase with google-play-billing successfully.
I can buy it from my app using the dummy card provided for testing by the google-play-billing library, but my purchase gets cancelled every time. Even at the time of purchasing, it shows
"the subscription will not automatically renew".

How to turn it into automatically renewable ???
Please help!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you acknowledging the purchase?

Comment: As per RBI's guidelines, subscriptions won't work in India https://www.xda-developers.com/google-play-suspend-free-trials-auto-renewing-subscriptions/

Comment: @user14678216 yes i did.. but, as pavi2410 said, i won't b able to do it anyways...

Comment: @pavi2410 thank you! i have been fighting this problem with one-to-another solutions/modifications ....but none worked, which frustrated me!  You saved my mental state now!

Comment: @pavi2410 - Only autorenewal is canceled, not subscriptions

Comment: @pavi2410Important: Due to the New Reserve Bank of India eMandate notification, your subscription experience may change as follows:
Free trials will be unavailable.
Auto-renewing subscriptions will be unavailable. All new subscriptions will be in the form of a single access pass. At the end of the pass duration, you’ll need to sign up again to continue your access.
This change will only apply to new subscriptions. Existing subscriptions will continue working as normal.